# How do I recreate these special characters when testing a website?

Tags: html, utf-8, internationalization

We have a 'contact us' form on a UK website which generates an email. Some users from European countries are entering company names such as "Törner" and "Ómicron" and the website is dealing with the characters correctly. Names like "João" are working with no trouble.

Occasionally, we will get a person's name, or company name that seems crazy:

> KovovÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™Ãƒâ€ Ã¢â‚¬â„¢ÃƒÆ’Ã¢â‚¬Â
>   ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â€šÂ¬Ã¢â€žÂ¢ÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â€šÂ¬Ã‚Â
>   ÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â¢ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â‚¬Å¡Ã‚Â¬ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â‚¬Å¾Ã‚Â¢ÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™Ãƒâ€
>   Ã¢â‚¬â„¢ÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â¢ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â‚¬Å¡Ã‚Â¬Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â
>   ÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¢ÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â¢ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â€šÂ¬Ã…Â¡Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¬ÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â¢ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â€šÂ¬Ã…Â¾Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¢ÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™Ãƒâ€
>   Ã¢â‚¬â„¢ÃƒÆ’Ã¢â‚¬Â
>   ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â€šÂ¬Ã¢â€žÂ¢ÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¢ÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â¢ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â€šÂ¬Ã…Â¡Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¬ÃƒÆ’Ã¢â‚¬Â¦Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¡ÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™Ãƒâ€
>   Ã¢â‚¬â„¢ÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â¢ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â‚¬Å¡Ã‚Â¬Ãƒâ€¦Ã‚Â¡ÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â€šÂ¬Ã…Â¡ÃƒÆ’Ã¢â‚¬Å¡Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â½roba
>   Navalany

Luckily this person made a second enquiry and this time the text was just:

> kovovyroba Navalany

Google reveals there is a place in Solvakia called Kovovýroba Navalaný. If I try to paste that into our website, it works fine. Another problem was from Germany where a single umlaut turned into hundreds of weird characters. Again, my own tests had no problems.

**My question is: How can I recreate the input which seems to make a single character balloon into 486 characters of gibberish?** Once I can cause the error myself, I can find the place in my code where I'm handling the text badly. I've pasted in the wildest, weirdest Turkish, Russian and Chinese characters, and not had any problems.

Comment: That should not usually happen, unless you are doing some funky character processing which may hickup under certain circumstances. I know of no standard process which could possibly result in such weirdness.

Comment: Not doing any funky processing. It is odd that a large variety of accents and umlauts and non-English-alphabet letters can survive intact...but one or two customers are capable of inputting something beyond that, which goes crazy.

Comment: I could not solve via escapeHTML and encoding. I need solution too.

Answer (score 1):

When I view a text field in PhpMyAdmin I sometimes get this string instead of an apostrophe:
ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â€šÂ¬Ã¢â€žÂ¢

The field type is set to text, and the collation is utf8_general_ci.

In my xojo application, I retrieve the text from MSSQL server, and the apostrophe appears as â€™.
(In SQL manager the apostrophe appears normally). 
I later store the text in the above-mentioned field in MySQL, with the results as shown. It looks like your case.

It looks like a character conversion is being compounded from ' to â€™ to ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â€šÂ¬Ã¢â€žÂ¢.
This doesn't explain the reason for it, but it does give you a pathway to reproduce the effect.

Answer (score 1):

@MagnusSmith You may want to try defining the encoding outright when getting the test from the field.

Remember that strings in Xojo do not necessarily have encoding defined. You might test it using [String.Encoding](https://docs.xojo.com/Encoding) and then convert or define it using [String.ConvertEncoding](https://docs.xojo.com/ConvertEncoding) or [String.DefineEncoding](https://docs.xojo.com/DefineEncoding), respectively.

Answer (score 0):

What seems to be happening is that the utf8 bytes are interpreted as latin1 characters, then converted to utf8.  Repeat *many* times.

I have often seen this happen twice with mis-configurations of MySQL, but never this may times.  In Allan's example:

```
’     E28099
â€™     C3A2 E282AC E284A2
Ã¢â‚¬â„¢  C383C2A2C3A2E2809AC2ACC3A2E2809EC2A2
ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â€šÂ¬Ã¢â€žÂ¢
```

In the original Question:

```
ý        C3BD
Ã½       C383 C2BD
ÃƒÂ½     C383 C692 C382 C2BD
ÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â½ C383 C692 C386 E28099 C383 E2809A C382 C2BD
(etc)
```

(As for what process is doing the nasty deed repeatedly, I don't know.)

As for undoing the deed.  Here is an example of undoing one step using MySQL:

```
SELECT CONVERT(BINARY(CONVERT('ÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â½' USING latin1)) USING utf8mb4)
                          --> 'ÃƒÂ½'
```

(I do not have a good way to "loop until finished".)

As for why some characters are OK, ans some are not, I don't see a pattern.

`ãöÓ` are OK?  but `ý’` are bad?  Interestingly `ãöÓ` have encodings in latin5, but the other two do not.  (Alas, this is the opposite of a useful pattern.)

Magnus - Could it be that the string was fetched and stored again repeatedly, as Allan suggests?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I cannot see how this might be looping, when all my webpage does is grab the typed values, and pass them to a SQL stored procedure to be saved once. But you've given me lots of great clues to look further into!

Comment: @MagnusSmith - When creating a Stored Procedure, the current charset is captured.  Check it with `SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE ...`  If it says "latin1", that _might_ be a strong clue.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to the party, but to add on to Rick James's answer, what's happening is that the text is repeatedly being encoded in UTF-8 and decoded in either ISO 8859-1 or Windows-1252 (known as "Western"), *many times.*

For example, in UTF-8:

```
ý        =C3=BD
```

The ý is encoded in UTF-8 where the two bits (C3 and BD) are supposed to be treated as a group, but if the target encoding is Western, the C3 and BD are erroneously decoded as individual bits:

```
Ã        C3
½        BD
```

But then this misinterpretation, for whatever reason, gets repeated, as "Ã½" is then encoded in UTF-8, producing two groups of two bits:

```
Ã        =C3=83
½        =C2=BD
```

then decoded as four individual bits in Western:

```
Ã        C3
ƒ        83
Â        C2
½        BD
```

then encoded in UTF-8:

```
Ã        =C3=83
ƒ        =C6=92
Â        =C3=82
½        =C2=BD
```

then decoded in Western:

```
Ã        C3
ƒ        83
Æ        C6
’        92
Ã        C3
‚        82
Â        C2
½        BD
```

then encoded in UTF-8:

```
Ã        =C3=83
ƒ        =C6=92
Æ        =C3=86
’        =E2=80=99
Ã        =C3=83
‚        =E2=80=9A
Â        =C3=82
½        =C2=BD
```

then decoded in Western:

```
Ã        C3
ƒ        83
Æ        C6
’        92
Ã        C3
†        86
â        E2
€        80
™        99
Ã        C3
ƒ        83
â        E2
€        80
š        9A
Ã        C3
‚        82
Â        C2
½        BD
```

and so on.

Here, I've shown what happens after four misinterpretations. In your case, the text has been misinterpreted ***eight times.***

Likewise, in Allan's example, the 3 bits representing the apostrophe are supposed to be interpreted as a group:

```
’        =E2=80=99
```

But if the target encoding is set to Western, the three bits are errouneously decoded as individual characters, producing the very famous **â€™** instead:

```
â        E2
€        80
™        99
```

At some point the characters, again, get re-encoded as UTF-8:

```
â        =C3=A2
€        =E2=82=AC
™        =E2=84=A2
```

then decoded in Western:

```
Ã        C3
¢        A2
â        E2
‚        82
¬        AC
â        E2
„        84
¢        A2
```

then re-encoded in UTF-8:

```
Ã        =C3=83
¢        =C2=A2
â        =C3=A2
‚        =E2=80=9A
¬        =C2=AC
â        =C3=A2
„        =E2=80=9E
¢        =C2=A2
```

then decoded in Western:

```
Ã        C3
ƒ        83
Â        C2
¢        A2
Ã        C3
¢        A2
â        E2
€        80
š        9A
Â        C2
¬        AC
Ã        C3
¢        A2
â        E2
€        80
ž        9E
Â        C2
¢        A2
```

and so on.

Comment: How on earth did your brain manage to spot this?!?! Amazing!

Answer (score 0):

You face **eightfold**/**octuple** [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*):

```
mojibake = 'KovovÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™Ãƒâ€\xA0Ã¢â‚¬â„¢ÃƒÆ’Ã¢â‚¬Â\xA0ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â€šÂ¬Ã¢â€žÂ¢ÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â€šÂ¬Ã‚Â\xA0ÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â¢ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â‚¬Å¡Ã‚Â¬ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â‚¬Å¾Ã‚Â¢ÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™Ãƒâ€\xA0Ã¢â‚¬â„¢ÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â¢ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â‚¬Å¡Ã‚Â¬Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â\xA0ÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¢ÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â¢ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â€šÂ¬Ã…Â¡Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¬ÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â¢ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â€šÂ¬Ã…Â¾Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¢ÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™Ãƒâ€\xA0Ã¢â‚¬â„¢ÃƒÆ’Ã¢â‚¬Â\xA0ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â€šÂ¬Ã¢â€žÂ¢ÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¢ÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â¢ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â€šÂ¬Ã…Â¡Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¬ÃƒÆ’Ã¢â‚¬Â¦Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¡ÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™Ãƒâ€\xA0Ã¢â‚¬â„¢ÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â¢ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â‚¬Å¡Ã‚Â¬Ãƒâ€¦Ã‚Â¡ÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â€šÂ¬Ã…Â¡ÃƒÆ’Ã¢â‚¬Å¡Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â½roba Navalany'
print( mojibake.encode('cp1252').decode('utf-8').
                encode('cp1252').decode('utf-8').
                encode('cp1252').decode('utf-8').
                encode('cp1252').decode('utf-8').
                encode('cp1252').decode('utf-8').
                encode('cp1252').decode('utf-8').
                encode('cp1252').decode('utf-8').
                encode('cp1252').decode('utf-8'))
```

**Output**: `.\SO\31671906.py`

> ```
> Kovovýroba Navalany
> ```